# checking array for values and then passing to new array. c

Tags: c, arrays

So given an array of:

```
input[3] = {0, 0, 0}
```

this outputs :

```
output[3] = {3, 0 ,0}
```

code:

```
void create_hist(double input[], int num_of_inputs, int output[])
{
    int num_to_check = input[0];
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_inputs; i++)
    {
        int j = output[i];
        if ((int)input[i] == num_to_check)
        {
            counter++;  /* it was found */
        }
        output[j] = counter;    
    }

    return;
}
```

but if I have a floating point array

```
 input[5] = {0.0000, 1.0000, 2.0000, 3.0000, 4.000}
```

and I want to truncate the values to `int`, and count how many times each integer in the range 0 - 10 appears in the input array then output it to:

```
output[5] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

output[0] = {1} //indicates how many times 0 appeared in the array
```

or

```
input[10] = {1.000, 4.000, 5.0000, 2.000, 4.000, 7.000, 9.000, 6.000, 0.000, 0.000}
```

and output

```
output[10] = {2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}

output[0] = {2} // this indicates how many times 0 appeared in the first array
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: I don't understand `int j = output[i];`. Why would you use a value from the output array as the index where `counter` should be stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `output[i]` as an array index. It's a counter, not the value whose count you want. You should use `(int)input[i]` as the index.

You first need to initialize all elements of `output` to `0`, then you increment the elements corresponding to the integer part of each input.

```
memset(output, 0, sizeof(output[0]) * MAX_INPUT_VALUE);
for (int i = 0; i < num_of_inputs; i++) {
    output[(int)input[i]]++;
}
```

Comment: Rather than  `memset(output, 0, sizeof(int) * MAX_INPUT_VALUE);`, code could assign with a simple  `memset(output, 0, sizeof output);` or initialize with `int input[3] = {0}`

Comment: @chux `output` is a pointer, so `sizeof output` won't work. And it's a function parameter so you can't initialize it in the function.

Comment: Fair enough As a pointer via a function pointer, `memset(output, 0, sizeof ouptu[0]` * MAX_INPUT_VALUE);` or `sizeof *output ...` is easier to code right and maintain as the necessity to match type and object is not needed.